# find a string within a tag without finding the tag in python

Tags: python, regex, bbcode

I have a string within a tag that I want to extract without finding the tag too. I tried:

```
string = re.search("\[tag\](.*?)\[tag\]", "[tag]string[tag]")
print(string.group(0))
```

and

```
string = re.search("/\[tag\](.*?)\[tag\]/i", "extra[tag]string[tag]extra")
print(string.group(0))
```

both return

```
[tag]string[tag]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.group(0)` is the entire match. Use `.group(1)` to get the section in parentheses that you want.

```
import re
string = re.search("\[tag\](.*?)\[tag\]", "[tag]string[tag]")
print string.group(1) # prints 'string'
```

---

- [Python 2.7 Documentation: re.MatchObject.group](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group)

Answer (score 2):

`group(0)` is the entire match. You want `group(1)`.

http://ideone.com/Q9sUt

Answer (score 1):

You can also use positive lookahead/lookbehind:

```
import re
text = """
          [tag]string[tag]
          [tag]string1[tag]
          [tag]string2[tag]
          [tag]string3[tag]
          [tag]string4[tag]
"""
print re.findall(r'(?i)(?<=\[tag\])\w*(?=\[tag\])', text)
```